# Assign tuple array from controller to tuple in tableviewCell

Tags: arrays, swift, tuples

```
var menuListItem: [(title: String, imageName: String, indexValue: Int)] = [
        ("Title Mode", "ModeImage" , 0), ("Contact Us", "ContactUsImage" , 1), ("Logout", "LogoutImage" , 2)]
```

//Assign Value to SideMenuCell

```
var sideMenuItem: (title: String, imageName: String, index: Int)?{
    didSet{
        self.setUpData()
    }
}

    func setUpData(){
        lblTitle.text = sideMenuItem?.0
        imageType.image = UIImage.init(named: sideMenuItem?.1 ?? "")
}
```

//Mark: - TableViewCell

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
      if let sideMenuCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: sideMenuCell) as? SideMenuCell{
            sideMenuCell.sideMenuItem = menuListItem[indexPath.row]
            return sideMenuCell
        }
}
```

I am getting error on this line.
sideMenuCell.sideMenuItem = menuListItem[indexPath.row]
**Cannot assign value of type '(title: String, imageName: String, indexValue: Int)' to type '(title: String, imageName: String, index: Int)'**

How to assign tuple [] into `UITableViewCell` tuple variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`index` is not the same as `indexValue`. Update your code as follows:

```
var menuListItems // this is plural. Add an "s".
```

```swift
struct SideMenuItem {
  let title: String
  let imageName: String
  let index: Int
}
```

```swift
var sideMenuItem: SideMenuItem? {
```

```swift
sideMenuCell.sideMenuItem = menuListItems.map(SideMenuItem.init)[indexPath.row]
```

Comment: Thanks for answer Its done by struct,  So Its will not possible by Tuple?

Comment: Not without writing it out more than `.init`. But if you're using a tuple in two places, you should use a struct instead.

Comment: Thank I used struct for following case remove tuple.